# Powershell CMD syntax

Tags: powershell, cmd, syntax

I have a line that works in cmd prompt but I cant convert it to work powershell, I can run it without errors in powershell but it doesnt function how it does in cmd prompt

```
"C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.69.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe" -F file=@C:\Documents\some.txt http://localhost/fileupload.php
```

I fixed it in case anyone comes across this one day

```
. ""C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.69.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe"" -F ""file=@C:\Documents\some.txt http://localhost/fileupload.php""
```

Comment: . ""C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.69.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe"" -F ""file=@C:\Documents\some.txt http://localhost/fileupload.php""

Answer (score 0):

I think your file=@C:\Doc... needs quotations.  file=@"C:\Doc..."

Comment: I am also sure I will need some quotation there, but its still not complete throws errors

Comment: Hrm, looks like something is also wrong with your -F flag, but I have no way of testing this right now, sorry.  This resource might help:

The escape character in Powershell is the "`" (backward apostrophe/grave), so maybe experiment with this around funky characters.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: @mooman - What errors does it throw? Please copy/paste them into the question as text.

Comment: Try piping the command to 2>&1 then look at $LASTEXITCODE for any errors.

Comment: Actually, looking at this with the native Windows curl, it does look like the -F flag is an issue - could it be that it's being interpreted as a format operator?